# Prevent blank line in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

Using `.erb`, you can do this:

```
<%= some_func -%>
```

I was wondering if there's a similar technique using `.haml`.

```
= some_func
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to explicitly remove the additional newline character using `chomp`:

```
= some_func.chomp
```

Another feature which may accomplish the task is the [space removal syntax](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_):

```
%div<
= "test          "
```

It returns the following html:

```
<div>test</div>
```